# Retrieve Values for User from Database

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently trying to retrieve values from a database.

New Users are given a UNIQUE ID once they register on my website:
[image]

Keys are stored into my database with a link such as:

`website.com/file.php?id=4&key=123abcd123`

[image]

What I was planning on having was the website pulling the keys ONLY related to the ID of the user.

Lets say User 4 inputs a key into the database, I want to have a universal .php file that will retrieve  HIS codes (codes with the ID of 4) ONLY.

I'm sorry if this doesn't really make sense, English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding particular record in mysql query pass the id value in the place of 4 below.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE UserID = '4'
```

if you want to get particular value then use like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE UserID = '".$_SESSION['ID']."'";
```

[Refference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-rows.html)

Comment: I ment to say that if User 4 logged into the page, it would show the keys tied to HIS number. Same goes with User 1, 2, 3, 5, 6...etc.

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE UserID = '$_SESSION['ID']'

Something like that^

Comment: Yes,OK,just replace 4 with your logged in user variable value. like SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE UserID =  '$_SESSION['ID']';

Comment: Thanks! Works a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL, it is easy to search for all keys for a user:

```
select  cdkey
from    YourTable
where   UserID = 1
```

Note that anyone can edit a URL.  So unless you take additional measures, any user could ask for the cdkeys of any other user, just by modifying the `id` parameter in the URL.